# Can Adobe AIR be used to create desktop/mobile apps written in Javascript that use the Web Audio API?

Tags: air, web-audio-api

Can I use Adobe AIR to create applications using Javascript and the Web Audio API and then have said applications still retain their audio functionality after they are turned into stand alone desktop/mobile applications. I have not started using Adobe AIR yet so I am not acquainted with the software.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think AIR's runtime includes Web Audio support; it may on iOS, if the user has iOS6 installed; won't have it on Android right now, and doubtful they keep it synced with current Chromium on desktop.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know of any similar package that could take a web app to the desktop or to a stand alone mobile app with a working Web Audio API implementation?